# Database entity model for an availability tool where there are multiple users selecting availability for multiple times across multiple weeks

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a database entity model structure for an user availability application. I have a number of users who will give their availability up to two weeks in advance for either AM/PM or EVE (evening) of each day of the week, I am unsure of how I should represent this as database tables.

My question is: How should I create the entity model? I am struggling to see how i can create this without having to build 52 tables for each week of the year, every year. Am I missing something extremely important/simple?

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create table UserAvailability (
    Id int Identity(1, 1) not null, -- primary key
    UserId int not null, -- FK to User table
    AvailabilityDay Date not null, -- Day of availability
    StartTime DateTime not null,
    EndTime DateTime not null
)
```

It would also have a unique key in UserInt + AvailabilityDay, unless you have multiple availability periods per user per day.

Cheers -

EDIT

After additional data:

```
create table UserAvailability (
    Id int Identity(1, 1) not null, -- primary key
    UserId int not null, -- FK to User table
    AvailabilityDay Date not null, -- Day of availability
    Morning bit not null default(0),
    Afternoon bit not null default(0),
    Evening bit not null default(0)
)
```

Note that this is actually in 2nd normal form, not third. Reporting requirements (and the rest of the DB) dictate whether it really should be in third.

Comment: Hi,  thanks very much for the reply! Unfortunately we have a possibility that there could be 3 availability periods per user per day.

Comment: Are they fixed periods?

Comment: the three options are Morning/Afternoon/Evening (there is no specific time frame dictated, they have those three options as check boxes)

Comment: Simon, thats absolutely fantastic thank you, I am assuming the table you've showed above is the link table between the user_details table and the Availability tables?

Comment: Not really. You only need a 'link table' for a M:M relationship. This IS the availability table. The relationship User:UserAvailability is 1:M and doesn't need anything else.

Comment: okay great, so if we have 30 users who all need to put their availability, the table you showed me will automatically create a table once one of the users submits their availability?

Comment: No. If there are 30 users who put in their availability for one day, your code there will be 30 rows in this table. What's this about creating tables? Why?

Comment: I think i am getting confused/worried about how many tables we will actually need for this database to function properly, as they give availability for two weeks in advanced, would i need a seperate table for every day?

Comment: You've got the date in the table up there. You have one table for Availability.

Comment: Okay, i will give it a go! the only two tables i will actually need then are the one you have provided and my user_details table?

Comment: Is there any other data you need to store? Write down the actual data you need to store and try to fit it in. If there isn't a slot for some of the data you'll either need extra columns on one of the tables or an extra table.

Comment: There isn't, I just need to know which user is available when for the next two weeks, I think that i have everything now, i will know once i have the interface created which pulls the data from the tables, thank you so much for your help today!